# Where does fungus store excess food?

Tags: food, mycology, mushroom

Can anyone pin point, as to where and how, the excess food is stored in fungus (mushroom to be specific).
Like plants store as starch granules, so where does mushroom store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia article on fungi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungus) (under Characteristics -> Shared Features):

> They have a characteristic range of soluble carbohydrates and storage compounds, including sugar alcohols (e.g., mannitol), disaccharides, (e.g., trehalose), and polysaccharides (e.g., glycogen, which is also found in animals).